# Reductions down a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a (well, many) column of return data to a column of closing prices. In Clojure, I'd use [`reductions`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/reductions), which is like `reduce`, but returns a sequence of all the intermediate values.

e.g.

```
$ c

0.12
-.13
0.23
0.17
0.29
-0.11

# something like this
$ c.reductions(init=1, lambda accumulator, ret: accumulator * (1 + ret)) 

1.12
0.97
1.20
1.40
1.81
1.61
```

NB: The actual closing price doesn't matter, hence using 1 as the initial value. I just need a "mock" closing price.

My data's actual structure is a DataFrame of named columns of TimeSeries. I guess I'm looking for a function similar `applymap`, but I'd rather not do something hacky with that function and reference the DF from within it (which I suppose is one solution to this problem?)

Additionally, what would I do if I wanted to keep the `returns` data, but have the closing "price" with it? Should I return a tuple instead, and have the TimeSeries be of the type `(returns, closing_price)`?

Comment: Ah, the function itself isn't the issue (should've written that above); that's easy enough. It's the (idiomatic, proper) application to the columns of the DataFrame that's the problem for me. Thanks, though!

Comment: Your description of your problem is a little hard to grasp in the abstract.  Can you provide sample data in your actual format with an example of what you actually want it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that it's often faster (as well as easier to understand) to write more verbosely in pandas, rather than write as a `reduce`.

In your specific example I would just [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) and then [`cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
In [2]: c.add(1).cumprod()
Out[2]: 
0    1.120000
1    0.974400
2    1.198512
3    1.402259
4    1.808914
5    1.609934
```

*or perhaps `init * c.add(1).cumprod()`.*

Note: In some cases however, for example where memory is an issue, you may have to rewrite these in a more low-level/clever way, but it's usually worth trying the simplest method first (and testing against it e.g. using %timeit or [profiling memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601041/pandas-wheres-the-memory-leak-here)).

Comment: Also worth noting that for this specific example (even with 1000 entries) it is much faster than the `expanding_apply` above.

Comment: Ah, updating pandas to 0.10.1 now; that should fix this.

Comment: You can do `(c+1).cumprod()`.  I'm getting the same error +1 for Andy's solution.  It's much faster than what I proposed.

Comment: @Zelazny7 When I typed this, I thought your method might be faster (and I can imagine some examples where it might be), but definitely a good idea to try the simplest (most pythonic?) method first :)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like it's a well publicized feature yet, but you can use `expanding_apply` to achieve the returns calculation:

```
In [1]: s
Out[1]:
0    0.12
1   -0.13
2    0.23
3    0.17
4    0.29
5   -0.11

In [2]: pd.expanding_apply(s ,lambda s: reduce(lambda x, y: x * (1+y), s, 1))

Out[2]:
0    1.120000
1    0.974400
2    1.198512
3    1.402259
4    1.808914
5    1.609934
```

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe `expanding_apply` works on the applied series starting from the first index through the current index.  I use the built-in `reduce` function that works exactly like your Clojure function.

Docstring for `expanding_apply`:

```
Generic expanding function application

Parameters
----------
arg : Series, DataFrame
func : function
    Must produce a single value from an ndarray input
min_periods : int
    Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value
freq : None or string alias / date offset object, default=None
    Frequency to conform to before computing statistic
center : boolean, default False
    Whether the label should correspond with center of window

Returns
-------
y : type of input argument
```

Comment: This is a very interesting function, I'm looking forward to playing with this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This works, except that I need to figure out how to deal with NaN data here (right now, just using a simple check e.g. `lambda x, y: x * (1+y) if pd.notnull(y) else x`, but that's not a great way of doing it, for obvious reasons…

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I prefer the following solution:

```
returns = pd.Series([0.12, -.13, 0.23, 0.17, 0.29, -0.11])

initial_value = 100
cum_growth = initial_value * (1 + returns).cumprod()

>>> cum_growth
0    112.000000
1     97.440000
2    119.851200
3    140.225904
4    180.891416
5    160.993360
dtype: float64
```

If you'd like to include the initial value in the series:

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.Series(initial_value), cum_growth]).reset_index(drop=True)
0    100.000000
1    112.000000
2     97.440000
3    119.851200
4    140.225904
5    180.891416
6    160.993360
dtype: float64
```